# Moved to another street. Can't reset eBay Password

Tags: ebay, account-recovery

I've forgotten my eBay password, but every time I try to reset my password and sign in, it kicks me out and I get an email saying that there's been "Fraudulent Access to your account"

It's either because of the fact that I moved to another street, or tried this with a new computer, but even when I try to do this with my older computers, the same thing happens.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you have tried to logging in and inputting the wrong password enough times from one IP address, there might be a period during which a fraud protection system might consider any attempt to login to your account as fradulent from that specific IP address.

I would try using some free VPN -service, which gives an IP from your country. Also waiting for some period of time might help. Hotspotshield is one option, just beware of the ads.